# Find a bilipschitz map from the boundary of a bounded convex domain of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $S^1$

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, convex-geometry, quasiconformal-maps

Let $G\subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$ be a bounded convex domain. I need to find a bilipschitz map from $\partial G$ to $S^1$, i.e. a map $f:\partial G\rightarrow S^1$ that satisfies for all $x,y \in \partial G$ that

$$ \frac{|x-y|}{L}\leq|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L |x-y|$$
for some constant L.

Supposing without loss of generality that the origin is in the interior of $G$ I was thinking about the map given by $f(x)=x/|x|$. If we take $m=\min \{|z|:z \in \partial C \}$ then we have

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
|f(x)-f(y)|&=\left|\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|}\right|\\&=\left|\frac{x|y|-y|x| + (x|x|-x|x|)}{|x| |y|}\right|\\& \leq \frac{|x|y|-x|x|| + |y|x|-x|x||}{|x||y|}\\&=\frac{||y|-|x|| + |y-x|}{|y|}\\& \leq \frac{2 |x-y| }{|y|}\\ & \leq \frac{2 |x-y| }{m}.
\end{split}
\end{align}

But I am having trouble proving that $m|x-y|/2 \leq |f(x)-f(y)|$

Any help would be highly appreciated.